# Do neural network multiclass classifiers automatically do argmax?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am a beginner in machine learning and is currently studying the basics of neural networks. In an example that I have seen, the last layer of the neural network happens to be

```
keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"),
```

Hence, output of the layer is **an array with 10 values corresponding to the class probabilities for each of the 10 classes in a multiclass problem**. However, the class labels in the original dataset is only an integer value, from 0-9. 
My question for this is, does my neural network automatically do argmax in its outputs to determine the label to compare with during training? Is there a way for me to explicitly know what operations my neural networks does 'implicitly'? Thank you!

Comment: Which loss are you using?

Comment: It turns out I was using sparse_categorical_crossentropy, so it handled the mismatch quite implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your labels using the below code so as the labels will become arrays (One Hot Encoding).

```
train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes = 10)
```

Example. For a label `2->[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`, For `1->[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` & likewise for other classes.

Comment: Thank you for the response! My question however is with regards to the training of the model. Since the output of my neural network is an array of size 10, and the class labels in the training set are integer values, does my neural network automatically compute for the argmax of its output array so that it can make its comparison with the original class labels? How does my neural network cope with the mismatch in output and class labels during training?

Comment: Yes! Apparently, I was using sparse_categorical_crossentropy as my loss function so the mismatch in outputs and labels are already taken care of. It took your comment and a bit of searching for me to realize this. Thank you!